# Graphviz - What is a valid style attribute?

Tags: graphviz, dot

The [Graphviz attributes documentation](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:style) describes the style attribute but does not say what values it may hold:

> Set style information for components of the graph. For cluster
>   subgraphs, if style="filled", the cluster box's background is filled.
>   If the default style attribute has been set for a component, an
>   individual component can use style="" to revert to the normal default.
>   For example, if the graph has
>
> ```
> edge [style="invis"]
> ```
>
> making all edges invisible, a specific edge can overrride this via:
>
> ```
> a -> b [style=""]
> ```
>
> Of course, the component can also explicitly set its style attribute
>   to the desired value.

What is a valid style attribute in Graphviz?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look closely, the [same documentation page](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#k:style) also specifies a Type named style describing valid styles. Excerpt:

> At present, the recognized style names are "dashed", "dotted",
>   "solid", "invis" and "bold" for nodes and edges, "tapered" for edges
>   only, and "filled", "striped", "wedged", "diagonals" and "rounded" for
>   nodes only. The styles "filled", "striped" and "rounded" are
>   recognized for clusters. The style "radial" is recognized for nodes,
>   clusters and graphs, and indicates a radial-style gradient fill if
>   applicable.

Comment: In `dot` it's legit to have a style that is *both* `rounded` *and* `filled`. I don't see any discussion of this issue here or in the docs.

Comment: `style="rounded,dotted"` worked for me, which resulted in _both_ `dotted` and `rounded` border of a node whith `box` shape